# HTML file is downloading instead of opening on apache server (AMPPS)

Tags: php, html, apache, http, ampps

yesterday i was playing with the http.conf file of my apache server to make it compile php inside html, it worked fine and all files was opening without problems, however today it keeps downloading html files instead of opening them, only the php file is working at the moment

my conf is as follow :

```
  <IfModule mime_module>
#
# TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
# filename extension to MIME-type.
#
TypesConfig conf/mime.types

#
# AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
# file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
#
#AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
#
# AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
# information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
#
#AddEncoding x-compress .Z
#AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
#
# If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
# probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
#
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
RemoveHandler .html .htm 
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
AddType application/x-tar .tgz
AddType image/x-icon .ico
AddType application/vnd.wap.wmlc .wmlc
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml .pwml .php5 .php4 .php3 .php2 .php .inc
AddType text/vnd.wap.wml .wml
AddType text/vnd.wap.wmlscript .wmls
AddType text/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc .wmlsc
AddType image/vnd.wap.wbmp .wbmp

#
# AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
# actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
# or added with the Action directive (see below)
#
# To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
# (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
#
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl

# For type maps (negotiated resources):
#AddHandler type-map var

#
# Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
#
# To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
# (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
#
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

P.s the "RemoveHandler .html .htm " line is one of the line that i have added yesterday so that it compile php in html, i tried removing it but still the same.

Comment: you must restart (reload) apache after a change like that.

Comment: i found out the problem, this        
// AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm \\
was missing
and yes thanks for reminding me to restart for each time i make a change i wasn't restarting

Comment: glad you're up and going. When you have a chance, write-up that as an answer and accept it. Helps others.

Answer (score 0):

i found out the problem, this 
// AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm // was missing